# wpf animation events overlapping

Tags: wpf

I've got a canvas control that grows in height when you move the mouse over it and shrinks back on mouse leave.

```
<Canvas x:Name="infoBar" Width="720" Height="39" Background="Red">
            <Canvas.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="infoBar" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            From="39" To="255" Duration="0:0:0.5" 
            />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="infoBar" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            From="255" To="39" Duration="0:0:0.5" 
            />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Canvas.Triggers>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock/>
                <TextBlock/>
           </StackPanel> 
        </Canvas>
```

This works fine. However if two quick consecutive events take place (mouseleave before mouse enter animation finishes) it goes nuts.

Is there anyway i can tell it to cancel out any other events that happen before an animation finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your event triggers you can perform pause, stop, resume, etc. commands on named storyboards.

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744905.aspx) should answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks you do answer my question. However i don't think i explained my problem clearly. My issue was that when events happen really quickly, the control would stop animating and just jump from minimum value to max value rapidly. Fixed it by removing the 'From' values from the animation.